# Open the file from :find in a :tabnew

Tags: vimrc, find

I have my fuzzy file finder in Vim and it does a pretty good job. But it always opens the file in the current tab. I want my `:find` to open the resulting file in a new tab.

I know I can `:tabnew <file>` but I need to write the complete file path here to open the file. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is

```
:tabfind
```

From `:help :tabfind`:

> Open a new tab page and edit {file} in 'path', like with :find.

Answer (score 3):

Ralf’s answer is the correct one, but I’ll add some more generically useful commands:

- Prepend `:vertical` to any command which splits and it will use a vertical split
- Similarly, prepend `:tab` to any command which splits and it will use a tab

These more general commands work for most things (so `:tab help` does what you thing), so they are good to have in your toolbox—especially for plugin authors, who may want to support `<modifiers>` in their `:command`s!

(Note that in this case you’d use `:sfind` for split, `:vertical sfind` à la `:vsplit`, and `:tab sfind` for tabs.)

Comment: I'm new to vim, and I'm liking it more and more. tab is like some "action" that you can add anywhere and it'll do the job right?

Comment: Kind of @Shantanu; it wont work for commands that dont open a split (e.g., `:tab function Foo()` is nonsense). But you’re on the right track! Give `:help :vertical` and `:help :tab` a read, if you haven’t already. Vim’s help rocks.